# Reference a static variable in one class from another class, Error qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, class, variables, reference, static

So i'm trying to access one static string from classA to classB using:

```
    public class classB
    {

        classA ca = new classA();

        //This is the value that i want from class B
        //Here it pops the following Error:
        string B = ca.A;
    }
```

In the real code i need the variable from classA as static because it changes the value after i run a internal method.

if string A in classA is declared as public static **Error: ClassA.A cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead**
If string A in classA is declared just as static **Error:ClassA.A is inaccessible due to its protection  level.**

```
public class classA
{
    static string A = "Hi";
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about C# [access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers).  The default access is `internal`, which means that `A is inaccessible to B`.

Comment: I edit my question, actually both classes are public including the variables.

Answer (score 1):

By default this field in your class `classA` is private. You should add a public keyword to it and to the class:

```
public class classA
{
   public static string A = "Hi";
}
```

And after that, you can access property `A` by using pattern`ClassName.PropertyName`, in your case it's:

```
classA.A
```

Comment: Correction - I believe it's "internal" :(

Comment: It's private by default. You can check this in the IL code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an object to access a static variable

```
class classA
{
    public static string A = "Hi";
}
class classB
{
    string B = classA.A;
}
```